# Problem class of assigning N persons to N tasks, zero costs with prefs

Tags: complexity-classes, assignment-problem, resource-allocation

I am looking for the general problem class / computational complexity / algorithms for the following problem:

*N tasks must be accomplished by N persons. 1 task to be done by exactly 1 person and vice versa. There is a binary preferences matrix whose (i,j) entry is 0 if person i can not do task j, and 1 if it can.*

There are no costs involved, no weights and the number of tasks equals the number of people.

I was searching for it but all I could find was the Assignment Problem which has costs/weights associated with each assignment.

As a last resort, perhaps I can transform my preferences matrix to a cost matrix if person can not do job then cost is infinite else cost is zero?

Comment: This problem is exactly __matching__. Refer to Wikipedia for further details.

Comment: you mean "maximum bipartite matching" ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory) ). i.e. construct a bipartite graph based on the prefs? Is max-flow the correct direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is known as *maximum matching* of a bipartite graph.
Basically let vertex $p_i$ (resp., $q_i$) represent the $i$th person (resp., task).
And we connect $p_i$ and $q_j$ with an undirected edge iff person $i$ can do task $j$.
The answer of the original problem is exactly the maximum matching of the new graph.

For algorithms, the classical [*Hungarian algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_algorithm), of complexity $O(n^3)$, is a nice choice. Certainly you can reduce this problem to network flow, and then apply any max-flow algorithm.
If you are looking for some "advanced" choices, refer to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)).